# How to refresh the page on nav dropdown change

Tags: angularjs, html

I've SPA using HTML5 and AngularJS. I've dropdown list in **index.html** in nav bar (Page header). I'm using indexController to bind the dropdown. On dropdown change i've to display data corresponding to the dropdown value in **dashboard.html** (using dashboardController.js) also in few other html pages similar to **dashboard.html**.

**Question**:

1. How to access the dropdown selected value in  dashboardController.js
2. How to refresh the **dashboard.html** upon dropdown change.

EDIT: I'm using this [NavBar](https://bootswatch.com/yeti/).

Comment: can you provide code of your html and js ? otherwise its impossible to reason about your case in details

Comment: It is general question. I guess no code sample is required.Even if i provide also doesn't help. I'm using Bootstrap menu with dropdown. thanks

Comment: if it's an SPA, why are you referencing different .html pages - dashboard.html and index.html? shouldn't it be one with 2 controllers in it - 'menuController' for menu changes and say 'dashboardController' for showing part of the page that has dashboard

Comment: You mean i can use same controller for all html pages? I think this can solve the problem. But, let say i've index.html (menu with dropdown), 1.html, 2.html and 3 html (active page) and i've index123Controller for all above 4.Now if i change dropdown.. how can i refresh 3.html page only? i mean active page only should refresh.

Comment: Yes., i can maintain single controller for all these and in init() method using this '$location.path().substring(1);' i can get the current active page and i can bind the values. I doubt whether this is a good approach or not?      Ex: I'm expecting same as http://www.amazon.com/. If you change the country  name then application behaves different.

Comment: if we still talk SPA, then 'current active page' term doesn't make sense. in SPA you have one page separated by zones (views, controllers, modules, whatever). If you just want to persist some user changes though all his session - you could use Cookies/localStorage for that, no angularjs required

Comment: if i use Cookies/localStorage to save the dropdown selected value.. how can i refresh the page?

Comment: May be i can use this http://jensrantil.github.io/refreshable-angularjs-service.html.